# How to setup a Bar Button with a value of firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to check if the user is a admin or not. If the user is a admin, I want to show a bar button. If not, the bar button should be hidden.

I call the following code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var beitraegeMelden: UIBarButtonItem!
var admin = false

func setupBarButton() {
    observeAdmin()
    if admin == true {
        self.beitraegeMelden.isEnabled = true
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.beitraegeMelden
    } else {
        self.beitraegeMelden.isEnabled = false
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
    }
}

func observeAdmin() {
    guard let currentUserUid = UserApi.shared.CURRENT_USER_ID else { return }
    let REF_ADMIN = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUserUid).child("admin")
    REF_ADMIN.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (admin) in
        let adminRecht = admin.value as? Bool
        if adminRecht == true {
            self.admin = true
        } else {
            self.admin = false
        }
    }
}
```

Here my database structure of the actually logged in user:

```
users
    currentUid
        admin: true
```

The admin value never gets true. 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a completion as the call to firebase is asynchronous

```
func observeAdmin(completion:@escaping((Bool) -> () )) {
    guard let currentUserUid = UserApi.shared.CURRENT_USER_ID else { return }
    let REF_ADMIN = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUserUid).child("admin")
    REF_ADMIN.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (admin) in
       completion( (admin.value as? Bool) ?? false )
    }
}
```

---

Call

```
observeAdmin { (res) in 
   self.beitraegeMelden.isEnabled = res    
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = res ? self.beitraegeMelden : nil
}
```

Comment: Works for me perfect thank you! One last question: I set the admin in my database so no member has a admin child except of me. How to handle it if all other users have no child admin? This time, when I log in with a user who has no admin child, I always get a fatal error. Thanks in advance for your help!